# How to use parameter__contains with SearchRank at Django?

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to use rank for ordering but also I need search with __contains for wide querying. How I can use `contains` and `SearchRank` at the same time?

```
vectors = SearchVector('title', weight='A') + SearchVector('title_english', weight='A') + SearchVector('content', weight='B') + SearchVector('content_english', weight='B')
    query = SearchQuery(value)
    articles = Article.objects.annotate(
        rank = SearchRank(vectors, query)
        ).filter(search__contains  = 'rank', category=category).order_by('rank')
```

Note: I can query with this way but can't order by rank

```
    vectors = SearchVector('title', weight='A') + SearchVector('title_english', weight='A') + SearchVector('content', weight='B') + SearchVector('content_english', weight='B')
    articles = Article.objects.annotate(
        search = vectors
        ).filter(search__contains = value, category=category)
```

Comment: can you share more code? I don t understand what you doing there

Comment: @Florin I only want to know way of  add __contains (%LIKE% expression in SQL) to query parameter at SearchRank process. My code is not complete. The code at above is just example

Comment: If you want to filter by a string not by foreignkey you can  do like this. `...filter(search__fieldName__contains=...). Where the `fieldName` is a fileld from foreignkey model

Comment: @Florin But I have to set SearchQuery for use SearchRank. Fot this reason I can't use search in filter

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AlexZaitsev unfortunately no